# Como verificar se uma variável é INT e a outra é uma String?

Tags: javascript

sou novo em javaScript e estou tentando fazer um game...
Preciso verificar se as duas entradas de dados são int e string.
"valor1" tem que ser inteiro e o "valor2" tem que ser uma string.
Podem me dizer se a lógica esta certa?

```
if((valor1== "") || (valor2== "")){
    alert("Prencha os campos corretamente...");
}else{
    if(((valor1%2) != NULL) && ((valor2%2) == NULL)){
        // chama outra função....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique o tipo da variável usando o comando `typeof`, armazene o valor em uma variável e verifique se o valor é o que você deseja. Segue um pequeno exemplo:

```js
valor1 = 1;
valor2 = '1';

tipoValor1 = typeof valor1;
tipoValor2 = typeof valor2;

console.log('tipo valor1: '+ tipoValor1);
console.log('tipo valor2: '+ tipoValor2);

if((tipoValor1 != 'number') || (tipoValor2 != 'string')){
    alert("Prencha os campos corretamente...");
}else{
    console.log('pode executar');
}
```

Se você estiver capturando de formulário com javascript puro, é provável que você terá de dar um `parseInt` na sua variável que deve ser número. Exemplo: `valor1 = parseInt('1');`.